# How do I seize a subset of seized resources?

Tags: anylogic

I have a pool of 25 agents (Operators). When an Order is generated, I seize a few Operators and move them to one of many different ProductionSuites as determined by a parameter in the Order.

Within the ProductionSuite, I have a variable of type ResourcePool that I would like to use to have these Operators perform tasks.

[image]

In the main window, I put this code in the "On seize unit:" code box:

```
agent.assignedSuite.suiteOperatorPool.addAgentToContents(unit);
```

but this triggers a NullPointerException error.  Am I using the addAgentToContents method incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not initialized your `suiteOperatorPool` variable, it's "initial value" field is empty. Hence, this is just an empty shell of type `ResourcePool` that cannot do anything, including adding agents to it.

You would need to initialize it properly using the ResourcePool API, but I don't think that is possible.

Also, you cannot have resources be part of 2 resource pools, as you are trying to do. You should think of a different way to solve your problem. Maybe rephrase the issue so we can think of alternatives. You might not need a RP at all but just use pure agent functionality...?

Comment: OK that makes sense. I can move them to the ProductionSuite node without seizing them in the main flowchart. Once within the node, is there a dynamic way to add Operator agents to an empty resource pool then?

Comment: not really. RPs are kinda limited here, unfortunately. Either create them at the model start in the correct quantity or use a schedule. But no manual adding. But you can do that yourself using agent behavior.